# Directory size in Azure Data Lake Store

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake, webhdfs

Is there a simple API using which I can get the size of an ADLS directory? preferably something in C#, but it's not a must.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient.FileSystem.GetContentSummary`:

```
var client = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(credentials);
ContentSummaryResult result = client.FileSystem.GetContentSummary(dataLakeAccount, path);
var dirSize = result.ContentSummary.Length;
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.datalake.store.datalakestorefilesystemmanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet).

Answer (score 3):

We could use the [Get Content Summary of a Directory REST API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Get_Content_Summary_of_a_Directory) to do that.

```
curl -i "http://<HOST>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=GETCONTENTSUMMARY"
```

C# code demo

```
 var url = "https://tomdatalake.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/tomtest?api-version=2017-08-01&op=GETCONTENTSUMMARY";
 var token = "eyJ0eX.....";
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
     var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
     var data = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 }
```

[image]

I also test it with PostMan.

[image]